# On formatting your phone where does all your media go that was previously placed in the vault?

Tags: factory-reset, gallery-vault

I recently did a factory-reset on my android phone which cleared all the apps and the media files including the ones I had in applock vault. Upon reinstalling the application appLock I could not find the media I uploaded there so I just want to know where these media files from the **vault** go and if there is a way to **recover** them?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkyeah.galleryvault) is the app that you used, then according to their FAQ (found in the [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkyeah.galleryvault) details in play store) the images are not stored online, and therefore were deleted during your factory reset. there is no easy way to restore them.

> Are my hidden files stored online? 
>   No. Your files are stored only on
>   your device, so please make sure to backup all your hidden files
>   before transferring to new device or factory reset